# "redirect_to" --on console i get message that page is redirected but on the browser the page doesn't get displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The create method is getting executed properly as shown on the console but redirect is failing to render on the browser.
controller

```
def create
  #try to authenticate the user - if they authenticate successfully, an instance of the User model is returned
  @user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  #if an instance is returned and @user is not nil...
  if @user
    #let the user know they've been logged in with a flash message
    flash.now[:notice] = "You've been logged in."
    #THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PART. Actually log the user in by storing their ID in the session hash with the [:user_id] key!
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    #then redirect them to the homepage
    redirect_to "/"
    return
  else
    #whoops, either the user wasn't in the database or their password is incorrect, so let them know, then redirect them back to the log in page
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem logging you in."
    redirect_to "/log-in"
    return
  end
end
```

console

```
Started POST "/log-in?              create=%7B%22method%22:%22PUT%22,%22responseType%22:%22json%22%7D" for 127.0.0.1         at 2015-05-21 12:51:36 +0530

Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML 
Parameters: {"email"=>"harsh@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "create"=>"{\"method\":\"PUT\",\"responseType\":\"json\"}", "session {"email"=>"harsh@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}

User Load (22.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'harsh@gmail.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
this is user entered passwordharsh
this is encript hash passwors$2a$10$kPfxXAMxcWHhJjcO9ubXv.Q2xbCMPA6K2epe/dGX5EDAIcbmnvJDi
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 307ms (ActiveRecord: 23.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-21 12:51:37 +0530 
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML   
Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms) 
Completed 200 OK in 349ms (Views:324.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I searched for similar questions and tried all the answers but its still not getting rendered on browser.
Please help if you know the answer

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` from the last lines. Rails looks for the redirection/rendering on the last line of the action being called. Let me know if that does the trick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work even after removing return. Infact i put return after seeing some answers for similar questions on stack overflow

Comment: @user3210312 can you explain more where you want to redirect. Because it looks like after succesful log in `POST "/log-in?" ` it redirects you to `localhost:3000/` which then renders the `users#index`. Where do you want it to redirect to?

Comment: i want it to redirect to the index page which i have set in the routes.rb file as `root 'users#index'`. So wen i redirect to `localhost:3000/` it should render the index page but it is not rendering the index page on the browser.